# Android - Create custom or override stock Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to create a camera that does 2 things:

1. shows a marker (+) in the center of the screen to help the user to focus on what he is recording
2. Records a video for a predefined (N) number of **frames** and then stops

In order to do that what is the best way? 
Does the Android Camera API offer me the ability to do these things or not? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html good tutorial how to use camera API

Comment: @EldarMensutov this is the first article i read. It doesn't cover what i want. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the marker, just put another view over top of the surface view that you will be using for camera preview..

The `android.media.MediaRecorder` class

has this method `setMaxDuration(int);`

look into this:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html